# InfoPath error that I need to fix

Tags: infopath

How do I fix this?

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at Change_Request.FormCode.FormEvents_OnSubmitRequest(DocReturnEvent e)
> at Microsoft.Office.Interop.InfoPath.SemiTrust._XDocumentEventSink2_SinkHelper.OnSubmitRequest(DocReturnEvent pEvent)

Comment: @Emily  Can you please provide some more infomation.  Where is the form submitting to? sharepoint, web services, database?

Comment: It is submitting to sharepoint but it is using a webservices

Answer (score 0):

try running the form in full trust. looks like you have a permission's issue.